# Remove Spaces inBetween the HTML tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have to remove spaces between the characters that are between the HTML Tags.

E.G

```
<option value="0" title="Advertising / Promotional Charges">Advertising / Promotional Charges</option>
```

I have used this code

```
.replace(/\>\s+\</g,'');
```

But its not working, I need the output like

```
 <option value="0" title="Advertising / Promotional Charges">Advertising/PromotionalCharges</option>
```

Comment: The tag is in document or is string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Don't try to use a simple regular expression to manipulate HTML. HTML is too complex for that and it *will* apply incorrectly. Instead, use an HTML parser (the DOM, for instance) and process the text nodes. ([Obligatory link about HTML and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454).)

Comment: @Mohammad I am getting html of the Dropdown

Comment: FYI The regex you posted will only match 1+ spaces *immediately following a closing bracket* (>).  If you think of HTML as a string rather than as a tree, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @Devdotnet back up 2 steps in your process.  Do you have the option values available as simple strings(ie. *before* they are inserted into HTML)?  If so, you can just do a simple `string.Replace(" ","")`.  Otherwise, would you be OK with a javascript-based solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`.replace(/\s+/g, '')`

on your text, not that DOM element itself.

This will match all (`/g` flag) whitespaces (`\s+`) and replace it with `''` (an empty string)

See working example below:

```js
$('select option').each((_, elem) => { // Loop over all options in the dropdown
  let currentText = $(elem).text(); // Get the current options text
  let newText = currentText.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // Remove whitespace
  $(elem).text(newText); // Set the text to the whitespace removed varient
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0" title="Advertising / Promotional Charges">Advertising / Promotional Charges</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nick, can't you see we're trying to shame OP in the comments above? :p

Comment: @JonathanWilson oh lol, I started writing this answer before I saw the comment xD

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use regular expressions to amend HTML as a string. Instead use the DOM to update the text of your `option` elements. You can still use a regular expression here, though. Specifically with the `\s` character class to remove all the whitespace. Try this:

```js
$('option').text(function(i, t) {
  return t.replace(/\s/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0" title="Advertising / Promotional Charges">Advertising / Promotional Charges</option>
  <option value="1" title="Foo / Bar">Foo / Bar</option>
  <option value="2" title="Fizz / Buzz">Fizz / Buzz</option>
</select>
```